# Live Face Recognition iOS adding 3D object

Tags: objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, ios5, avfoundation

I need to create an iOS 5 application will run on iPad2 (*I can use private API because the App will not be released in App Store*) will show live stream from front camera, recognize eyes and render a pair of glasses (I have the 3D model) following face movements.

Which is the best approach and the best technology (e.g. OpenGL ES) I can use?

Comment: are you able to solve that issue ? , did you find any library ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the libraries included in XCode. I have a sample [here](https://github.com/theinfamousrj/LaughingMan). It's got everything you need.

It uses the AVFoundation, CoreImage, CoreMedia, and CoreVideo frameworks.

Comment: This sample is not exactly what I'm looking for (there no rotating "3D" object following the rotation of face, like real glasses), but it's a really good starting point about AVFoundation and Face (eyes and mouth) recognize.

Comment: I didn't realize you weren't going to render the model and make it into an image beforehand. It's definitely a good starting point though. I believe you can just use the OpenGLES framework for rendering.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your project with the detailed comments, great for understanding.